# ajax concatenar el contenido de el success callback para acceder a una parte del objeto mediante string

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

necesito hacer una función en JavaScript que al pasarle por parámetros varios string se concatene con el objeto result y me de la información respectiva de esa parte del objeto. El ultimo div que al intentar escapar las comillas no lo he hecho bien y no recarga la sección bien.

Respuesta Ajax

```
public function destroy(Estudios $estudio)
    {
        try {
            $estudio->delete();
            return response()->json(['estudios'=>'borrado con exito','clase'=>'text-capitalize bg-green-100 border-t border-b border-green-500 text-green-700 px-4 py-3']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['estudios'=>'Error, no es posible borrar el registro','clase'=>'bg-red-100 border-t border-b border-red-500 text-red-700 px-4 py-3']);
        }
    }
```

Funcion en el archivo js

```
function eliminar(url,divMensaje,divRow,clase,contenido ){
        ajaxSetup ();
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'DELETE',
           success: function(result) {
             $(divMensaje).append('<div class="'+result+'.'+clase+'" role="alert"><p class="font-bold">'+result+'.'+contenido +'</p></div>');
             $(divRow).load(location.href +"/"+divRow+"/>*", "");
           }
        });
    }
```

La idea es llamar a esta funcion eliminar en un boton con jQuery tal que así:

```
 $( "#rowEstudios" ).on("click", "[name=deleteEstudios]", function() {
        let id= $(this).val();
        ajaxSetup ();
      eliminar('estudios/'+id,"#estudiosMensaje","#estudiosRow",'clase','estudios');
            }
        });
    });
```

Lo que necesito es encontrar la forma de concatenar tanto clase como estudios(que en este ejemplo es estudios pero tengo como 5 secciones con diferente ids que son lo mismo) para poder reutilizar el botón y no tener que estar creando el contenido del botón si no llamar a esta función pasarle los parámetros convenientes y a volar

Comment: Agrega el código donde se procesa ese **result** y se mas especifico en lo que quieres obtener, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia lo que quiero es poder concatenar la variable result que me viene desde el servidor es una respuesta ajax para no tener que poner los mismos nombres a las variables y así poder tener un código que atienda a diferentes llamadas.